# How to skip/insert half of a line height in html or asp.net aspx file?

Tags: asp.net, html

I use `<br />` to do a line break in an aspx file.

This gives me more line height than I want. Meaning too much blank space between the lines. How do I insert or skip just half of a line height in aspx or html?

BTW, I am using an `asp:Label` control on the following line if this info can be useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like:

CSS

```
.half-line {
  line-height: .5em;
}
```

and then add `<p class="half-line">&nbsp;</p>` instead of your `<br>` tag

Or instead of using `<br>` tags, you could just set the `margin-bottom` on your `<p>` tags smaller.

Comment: As far as I understand 1em is not your line height. That means 0.5em is not half of your line height.

Answer (score 1):

<SUP>&nbsp;</SUP>

Superscript adds a half-line above the line it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my attempt at getting exactly half a line break.
https://codepen.io/qkeave/pen/oqQLBN

It is unfortunate but important to remember that 1em is not the same height as 1 line.

Try this instead:

```
p:after{
    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    line-height: ($yourLineHeight/2);
}
```